# C - freopen() for redirecting needs fclose()?

Tags: c

After a call like freopen(file_name, open_mode, stderr), do I need to call fclose(stderr) before the process ends or it is done automatically  ?
thanks in advance and sorry for my English

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to close an open stream as all open streams are closed at program termination but it is good practice to have a `fclose` for every `fopen` call. In the case of `stderr` here, this stream is already open at startup (you didn't have to call `fopen`) and so I see no reason to explicitly close it even if some `freopen` calls were issued.

Comment: In general I would agree, except for the standard 3 streams. See my comment on phihag's answer.

Comment: @R. I didn't really notice it was `stderr` here. Actually I would also not close it. There is no associated call to `fopen` in the program so I see no reason to call `fclose` for `stderr` even if there is some `freopen` calls.

Answer (score 2):

When a process ends, all its handles are closed automatically. However, it is good style to close every handle **you acquire** - for example, somebody may want to convert your program to a library, or you may be looking for leaks. Whether you call `freopen` does not matter for that.

**However**, in the case of stderr, the situation is a little bit different. Since you didn't specifically open that stream, you shouldn't close it. It's also very likely to be used by other components out of your control, for example atexit functions or stack smashing detection.

Comment: Closing any of the standard files (stdin/out/err) is a rather bad idea. Any use of a file stream after it's closed results in undefined behavior, and it's possible that code you're not aware of will try to access one of these (*especially* stderr) after you close it -- for example, a library which has registered an `atexit` handler and which experiences an error during its cleanup code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is good practice, but not strictly necessary if your process will end immediately since the OS will clean everything up for you when the process dies.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. And simply `fclose(stderr);` will do.